# Compare last two values in a selection [Excel]

Tags: excel-formula

I made a formula to compare the values of the last two non-empty cells in a range (M48-X48), and according to the difference between the values to give me an output (u, p, or q). However, if the range has an empty cell between the last two values the formula doesn't work anymore, because I simply subtract 1 cell from the index of the last value, instead of going back to the last non-empty cell. How can I add this feature to the formula?

```
=IF((INDEX(M48:X48;MATCH(9E+99+307;M48:X48))-INDEX(M48:X48;MATCH(9E+99+307;M48:X48)-1))=0;"u";IF(INDEX(M48:X48;MATCH(9E+99+307;M48:X48))-INDEX(M48:X48;MATCH(9E+99+307;M48:X48)-1)>0;"p";"q"))
```

Example the way it works now:

```
M: 1; N: 2; O: 3; rest until X is empty
Output = p
```

Example raneg which causes an error:

```
M: 1; N: empty; O: 3; rest until X is empty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the AGGREGATE function the last to non-empty values can be easily extracted.

The solution to the question is the following

```
=IF(INDEX(M48:X48;AGGREGATE(14;6;COLUMN(M48:X48)/(M48:X48>0);1)-12)-INDEX(M48:X48;AGGREGATE(14;6;COLUMN(M48:X48)/(M48:X48>0);2)-12)=0;"u";IF(INDEX(M48:X48;AGGREGATE(14;6;COLUMN(M48:X48)/(M48:X48>0);1)-12)-INDEX(M48:X48;AGGREGATE(14;6;COLUMN(M48:X48)/(M48:X48>0);2)-12)>0;"p";"q"))
```

The component *AGGREGATE(14;6;COLUMN(M48:X48)/(M48:X48>0);1)* returns the column number of the last value, while the same component with a 2 instead of a 1 at the end, returns the column of the second last value. Using INDEX(component-12) the value of the corresponing cell is returned. The -12 is needed to account for the column shift because the range starts only at M. The rest of the formula stays unchanged from the way it was asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do a find and replace, blanks with zero's in your data range?

You could drop IF statements into your index/match but the longer they get, the longer they take to calculate in my experience and wondering if its worth the time investment. You tell me.

Comment: No, a find and replace with zeros would not work. The IF statement compares the last two values, so if I replaced a second-last empty cell with a zero, then this is what my last value will be compared to and not the actual second-last value in that range.